# Switch between fragment

Tags: java, android

I have implemented a BottomNavigationView which allows the user to switch between fragments. But now I want to trigger this manually in the program using another button. This button is located in a snackbar. (See code)

```java
Snackbar.make(BLEFragment.this.getView(),"BLE IS NOT ENABLE ! \n go to the settings-tab,...",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .setBackgroundTint(Color.rgb(244, 78, 63))
        .setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255))
        .setAction("Settigs", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        })
        .show();
```

Maybe you can help me here.

If I have formulated the question wrong. I would like to apologize. I do not know how to formulate it differently.

Thank you very much.

Ramsauer René

Answer (score 0):

Snackbar is a control in the Android Support Design Library, which can quickly pop up messages at the bottom of the screen.

Snackbar.make（View view, CharSequence text, int duration）

You can check the parameters and corresponding API

Comment: Yes, I know.
I can also use a button in this case. My problem is how to change the fragment.
In this case I will navigate to the settings fragment.

Comment: use FragmentTransaction API

Answer (score 0):

**bottomNavigationView.getMenu()** will resolve your issue.try this

```
Snackbar.make(BLEFragment.this.getView(),"BLE IS NOT ENABLE ! \n go to the settings-tab,...",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .setBackgroundTint(Color.rgb(244, 78, 63))
            .setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255))
            .setAction("Settigs", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                 //Move to next fragment
                    switchFragment(R.id.more_setting);
                }
            })
            .show();



public void switchFragment(int idd) {
        Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
        for (int i = 0, size = menu.size(); i < size; i++) {
            MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
            if(item.getItemId() == idd){
                item.setChecked(true);
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new ProgramFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }

        }
    }
```

in activity which holds fragment views

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    if (count == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

Comment: This basically works but if I execute this line `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new ProgramFragment()).commit();` I can't navigate back via the BottomNavigationView anymore. And if I don't run it, only the icon is selected but the fragment is not changed.

Comment: I updated code  you can achieve this by adding .addToBackStack(null) and customize onBackPressed method with above code

Answer (score 0):

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/galaxyContainer">
</FrameLayout>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/galaxyBottomBar"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:paddingVertical="6dp"
        app:fabCradleMargin="8dp"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="30dp"
        app:fabAnchorMode="cradle"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
        app:elevation="10dp"
        app:addElevationShadow="true"
        app:fabAnimationMode="slide"
        app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">
            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/galaxyExploreButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/galaxy_btn_explore"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="Explore"
                android:textColor="@drawable/galaxy_tab_text"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/galaxyGalleryButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/galaxy_btn_gallery"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="Gallery"
                android:textColor="@drawable/galaxy_tab_text"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here goes my java code

```
public void switchTab(boolean isExplore) {
    exploreButton.setSelected(isExplore);
    galleryButton.setSelected(!isExplore);
    FragmentTransaction ft = `enter code here`getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.galaxyContainer, isExplore ? new ExploreFragment() : new GalleryFragment());
    ft.commit();
}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   switchTab(v.getId() == R.id.galaxyExploreButton);
}
```

Hope this would help.